# Why the docker-compose.yml file is not working on Windows 10? But the same file can work on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

- docker version (MacOS)

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

- docker version (Win 10)

```
Client:
 Version:           18.03.0-ce
 API version:       go1.9.4
 git commit:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           falsews/amd64
 Orchestrator:      swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.6
  API version:      go1.10.8inimum version 1.12)
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          false/amd64
  Experimental:
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:

    web:
        image: acc:v1
        container_name: web
        # privileged: true
        ports:
            - "9090:8000"
        links:
            - db
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./code/:/usr/src/app/web/
        networks:
            - account
        restart: always
        command: bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"

    db:
        image: db:v1
        # privileged: true
        ports:
            - "9906:3306"
        container_name: db
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - account

    nginx:
        image: nn:v1.1
        # privileged: true
        ports:
            - "8082:80"
            - "8083:8080"
        container_name: nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
            - web
        links:
            - web
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/:/root/html/
        networks:
            - account

networks:
    account:
        driver: bridge
```

- MacOS is ok.

```sh
$ docker-compose up -d
```

- Win 10 is not.

  1. step one

```sh
$ docker-compose up -d
error: can't create..: No command specified.
```

2. step two
   ==> add command in .yml file

```
...
        networks:
            - account
        command: /bin/bash
...
```

```sh
error: OCI runtime create failed:..(345):starting container process caused "exec : /bin/bash":stat /bin/bash: No such file or directory: unknow.
```

3. step three
   ==> alter command

   - I tried sh | /bin/bash | /bin/sh | ls | /bin/ls | and so on.

It is so weird.
I want to run the containers with the docker-compose.yml file on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but ask if you have a Ubuntu or Linux bash environment to run bash commands in Windows.

http://techgenix.com/bash-on-windows-10/
You would need to have it be able to run this command: 
`in your Docker-compose.yml command: bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"`